# How to sign in in MVC Web Application using dbContext and MySQL Database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I have a web application using MVC and MySql for the database. How created a sign in form but I don't know how to sign in using `DbContext`. I tried it but doesn't work:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(AccountModel objAccount)
{
    if(objMyDbContext.ObjAccountModel.ToList().Count==1) return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `IdentityUser` and `signInManager` that provides inbuilt login support.